# math.round and moving divs randomly on a page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to move each div in a page randomly. This code works, but all divs move together. I want each div to move in different ways. How can I achieve this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
animateDiv();

});

function makeNewPosition(){

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh,nw];    

    }

    function animateDiv(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $('.a').offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $('.a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDiv();        
    });

    };

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

    return speed;

}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FGwME/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FGwME/

Comment: this link can help  to see all of my codes

Comment: function randomcolor() { var r = randomNum(255); var g = randomNum(255); var b = randomNum(255); var color = 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')'; return color; };

Comment: write this code for random collor but i dont know where i must call back this function i want my div collor change randomly

Answer (score 2):

edit to make it continuous

```
function animateAllDiv () {
     $('.a').each(function() {animateDiv($(this));});

}

function animateDiv ($e){

     var newq = makeNewPosition();
     var oldq = $(this).offset();
     var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

     $e.animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed,function() {animateDiv($e);} );

   });

 };
```

Comment: thnx work but work once time i want to move again and again please "D

Comment: For making it continuous, try using $(this).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDiv();        
    });

Comment: function randomcolor()
  {
   var r = randomNum(255);
   var g = randomNum(255);
   var b = randomNum(255);
   var color = 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
   return color;
  };

Comment: i write this code for random collor but i dont know where i must call back this function i want my div coller change randomly

Comment: don't use the callback this way it will callback at every div; use `setInterval` to have your animateDiv called every xxx ms

Comment: bro i want change collors  how i do that i want change collr with my function randomcollor

Comment: function randomcolor() { var r = randomNum(255); var g =      randomNum(255); var b = randomNum(255); var color = 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')'; return color; };